# How can you get the most recent business day in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

How can you get the most recent business day in python?

E.g., if today is a business day, I'd like to get today as a datetime object, but if today is a Sunday, I'd like to get Friday as a datetime object, presuming Friday is the most recent business day.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.datetime.today() - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(0)
```

**Update**

```
today = pd.datetime(2018,9,2)

np.where((today - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(0)) > today,
         (today - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)),
         (today - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(0)))

[output]
Timestamp('2018-08-31 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Seems like overkill to me to import `pandas` just for that but..

Comment: Chris if I do `datetime.datetime(2018,9,2) - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(0)`, I would hope to get 31st August 2018 (most recent business day) but I instead get 3rd September (in the future). Is there anything I can do to correct this?

Comment: Hey @Jack I updated my answer. It's not particularly elegant, but should solve your problem for now. I'll have a play and see if there is a better solution

Comment: `pandas` is often imported

Comment: Hi Chris, Does this include holidays for say something like the stock market?

Comment: Your updated version could be replaced by `pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1).rollback(today)` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BDay.rollback.html)).